# Order by mapped string instead of integer

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, sql-order-by, paging

In the Database table "Device" have a column "Status" (integer)

```
Name    |  Status
----------------
Device1     1
Device2     2
Device3     3
Device4     4
Device5     3
```

In my Application I have map the column "Status" to human readable words (string)

```
public enum Status
{
   Start = 1,
   Stop = 2,
   Running = 3,
   new Device = 4,
}
```

If I order by "status" the result will be order by integer.

```
_repository.Query<Device>().OrderBy(c=>c.status)
                           .Skip(skip)
                           .Take(500);
```

In the table "Devices" I have more than 60.000 records, so I use paging

Result:

```
Name     |   Status
------------------
Device1     Start 
Device2     Stop 
Device3     Running 
Device5     Running 
Device4     new Device
```

What  I need:

```
Name     |   Status
------------------
Device4     new Device
Device3     Running 
Device5     Running 
Device1     Start 
Device2     Stop
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the conditional operator:

```
var query = _repository.Query()
    .OrderBy(c => c.Status == Status.NewDevice ? 0 : c.Status == Status.Running ? 1 : c.Status == Status.Start ? 2 : 3)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the number?

```
public enum Status
{
   Start = 3,
   Stop = 4,
   Running = 2,
   new Device = 1,
}
```